# Why do I get an "internal error setting the array" error when editing a mesh with Python?

Tags: python, animation, mesh, scripting

I want to update an object's mesh (only vertices and edges, plus screw modifier) at every new frame via `frame_change_pre`. This is my code:

```
import bpy
import numpy as np

def get_mirror_vertices_dummy(frame):
    zpos = np.array([0., 1.]);
    rpos = np.array([0., np.sin(frame/10.)]);
    return zpos, rpos, [], [];

def create_mirror_mesh(mesh, frame):
    # mesh arrays
    verts = [];
    edges = [];

    zpos, rpos, zneg, rneg = get_mirror_vertices_dummy(frame);

    # calculate vertices
    for vertexID in range(0,zpos.size):
        x = rpos[vertexID];
        y = 0.;
        z = zpos[vertexID];

        vert = (x,y,z);
        print(vert);
        verts.append(vert);

    # fill edges
    for vertexID in range(0,zpos.size-1):
        edge = (vertexID, vertexID+1);
        print(edge);
        edges.append(edge);

    # create mesh from data calculated above
    mesh.from_pydata(verts, edges, []);
    mesh.update();

def add_mirror():
    # create mesh and object
    mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("mirror");
    mesh.update();
    object = bpy.data.objects.new("mirror", mesh);
    # set mesh location
    object.location = bpy.context.scene.cursor.location;
    bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(object);

    # add screw modifier
    object.select_set(state=True)
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = object;
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='SCREW');

def mirror_update(frame):
    # if object does not yet exist, create it
    if not 'mirror' in bpy.data.objects:
        add_mirror();
    # delete old mesh first
    mesh = bpy.data.meshes['mirror'];
    #bpy.data.meshes.remove(mesh);
    create_mirror_mesh(mesh, frame);

def mirror_update_handler(scene):
    frame = scene.frame_current;
    mirror_update(frame);

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(mirror_update_handler);
```

When I run it in Blender (v2.82.7) in a fresh, empty scene, the first time I jump to a new frame, the object gets created and the mesh is also appearing. However, when jumping to another frame, I get the error

```
Error: Array length mismatch (expected 12, got 6)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Text", line 61, in mirror_update_handler
  File "/Text", line 57, in mirror_update
  File "/Text", line 33, in create_mirror_mesh
  File "/snap/blender/37/2.82/scripts/modules/bpy_types.py", line 469, in from_pydata
    self.vertices.foreach_set("co", tuple(chain.from_iterable(vertices)))
RuntimeError: internal error setting the array
```

I tried to remove the mesh before calculating the new vertices by un-commenting the line

```
bpy.data.meshes.remove(mesh);
```

in the function `mirror_update`. When I run this and jump to a new frame, the mesh is deleted and I get the error:

```
Error: Array length mismatch (expected 18, got 6)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Text", line 61, in mirror_update_handler
  File "/Text", line 57, in mirror_update
  File "/Text", line 33, in create_mirror_mesh
  File "/snap/blender/37/2.82/scripts/modules/bpy_types.py", line 469, in from_pydata
    self.vertices.foreach_set("co", tuple(chain.from_iterable(vertices)))
RuntimeError: internal error setting the array
(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
(0.3894183423086505, 0.0, 1.0)
(0, 1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Text", line 61, in mirror_update_handler
  File "/Text", line 57, in mirror_update
  File "/Text", line 33, in create_mirror_mesh
ReferenceError: StructRNA of type Mesh has been removed
```

The strange thing is: when I now comment-in again this line and run it afterwards, it works exactly as expected.

Can someone spot what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by replacing `bpy.data.meshes.remove(mesh);` with `mesh.clear_geometry();`.